# Switch custom page with project Overview page in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to switch the default project Overview page with my custom page in Sonarqube?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. However, it is possible to [add additional pages](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Creating+a+Page) to the interface. They'll show up under the 'More' menu.